# How to solve the problem of low performance of complex video generation using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I use ffmpeg to generate a complex video.

**This video consists of the following materials:**

1. Original video
2. Video dub
3. Background music
4. Subtitle

**My code logic is as follows**

1. Combine 'Original video' and 'Video dub' into 'Video A'
2. Subtitle 'Video A' as 'Video B'
3. Add 'Background music' for 'Video B' as 'Video C'

The 'Video C' is the video I want.

**My Code**

```
// Step1:
ffmpeg -i VideoDub.mp3 -i OriginalVideo.mp4 VideoA.mp4
// Step2:
ffmpeg -i VideoA.mp4 -vf subtitles=Subtitle.srt -y VideoB.mp4
// Step3:
ffmpeg -i VideoB.mp4 -i BackgroundMusic.mp3 -filter_complex "[1:a]aloop=loop=-1:size=2e+09[out];[out][0:a]amix" -ss 0 -t 100 -y VideoC.mp4
```

**Design defect**

- I think my code is very redundant
- poor performance
- There are many times of encoding
- It takes too long to generate such a video
- The CPU usage has reached 100%.

**My Question**

How to solve the above problem？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a filter_complex to perform all filtering in one command.

```
ffmpeg -i OriginalVideo.mp4 -i VideoDub.mp3 -stream_loop -1 -i BackgroundMusic.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:v]subtitles=Subtitle.srt;[2][1]amix" -ss 0 -t 100 VideoC.mp4 -y
```